# Intervall of definition of the solution of a Cauchy problem

Tags: real-analysis

I have the Cauchy problem: $y'+(y^2+y-3/4)cosx=0$ with $y(0)=y_o$.
I have to found the maximal intervall of definition for the solution.
If $y_0=1/2$and $y_0=-3/2$ the solution are constant and defined on all R.
In the other cases can I to calculate the expression of the solution (the ED is a separable variables)?

I have found: $|\frac{2y(x)-1}{2y(x)+3}*\frac{2y_o+3}{2y_o-1}|=e^{-2sinx}$.

So $y(x)=-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{2y_0+3}{2y_0+3-(2y_0-1)e^{-2sinx}}$.

the intervall of definition is ${2y_0+3-(2y_0-1)e^{-2sinx}}\ne0$?

Answer (score 1):

***Just a hint...***
$$y'+(y^2+y-3/4)\cos(x)=0$$
$$y'+(y^2+y+\frac 14 -1)\cos(x)=0$$
$$y'+((y+\frac 12)^2 -1)\cos(x)=0$$
Substitute $z=y+\frac 12$
$$z'+z^2\cos(x)=\cos(x)$$
its separabe
$$z'=(1-z^2)\cos(x)$$
$$\int \frac {dz}{(1-z^2)}=\int \cos(x)dx=\sin(x)+K$$
$$\ln|{1+z}|+\ln|{1-z}|=2\sin(x)+K$$
$$\ln|{\frac 32+y}|+\ln|{\frac 12-y}|=2\sin(x)+K$$
$$K=\ln|{\frac 32+y_0}|+\ln|{\frac 12-y_0}|$$
$$....$$